# How to create user page for each user from react and firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new to react and firebase authentication. I wanted to know how to create a page for each user signed in, in my website. For example, a user named "Max" signed up in my webpage and the program should make a user page for him. So when another user goes to "Myapp.com/user/max" it should show Max's page.

Can you give me concept and idea for it?

My signup looks like this:-

```js
import React from "react"
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "./firebase"
import fire from "./firebase"
function Signup(){
    const history = useHistory()
    function signUp(){
        let uEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
        let uPassword = document.getElementById("password").value;
        let userName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
        async function send(email, password){
            await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(()=>{
                console.log("successfull");
                let userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
                console.log(userID)
                firebase.database().ref("users/"+userID+"/praivate/login credentials").set({
                    "userName": userName,
                    "userId": userID,
                })
            })
            history.push("./login")
        }
        send(uEmail, uPassword);
    }
    return(
        <div id = "signUp">
               <input id = "email" placeholder = "email" />
               <input id = "password" placeholder = "password" />
               <input id = "userName" placeholder = "username" />
               <button onClick = {signUp}>Enter</button>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Signup
```

and my app js looks like this:-

```js
import check from "./component/checkAt"
import './App.css';
import Nav from "./component/nav"
import Header from "./component/header"
import About from "./component/about"
import Home from "./component/home"
import Login from "./component/login"
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import fire from "./component/firebase";
import Signup from "./component/Signup"
//import auth from "firebase/auth";
let log;

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      
      <Router>
        
      </Router>
      <Router>
        
        <Switch> 
          <Route path="/" exact component = {Home} />
          <Route path="/about" exact component = {About} />
          <Route path="/login" exact component = {Login} />
          <Route path = "/Signup.js" exact component = {Signup} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      
    </>
  );
  
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Add some routing/navigation to your application and define a route/path that matches "/user/:userId" and render a page component that accesses the `userId` parameter and loads the correct data to the page. Try something and provide an updated question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a route that takes parameters.

`<Route path="/user/:name" component={UserComponent} />`

And same goes for the backend, make a public route.

Answer (score 1):

Define a `Route` in your `Switch` that uses a dynamic path.

```
<Route path="/user/:userId" component={UserPage} />
```

The "UserPage" component will receive [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) (`history`, `location`, and `match`). The path parameters are on the [match](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/match) prop at `props.match.params.userId`.

```
const UserPage = ({ match }) => {
  const { params: { userId } } = match;
  // do with `userId` what you need to load that user's data

  ...
};
```